# about socket.startHandshake(); in java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have a small Java program that reads list of IPs from text file and inside a loop it create ssl session with the ip. The session might succeed or fail depend whether the port 443 is enabled in the other side or not.

My problem: 
1. If port 443 is not enabled in the other side, the session will fail. The problem is that my program stops here and go to exception handling and print me the error and ends. I want the program to continue creating the next session with the next IP and so on. How can I make it continue and print out a message saying that the session failed for that IP?

Another issue: How can I get the enabled cipher suite? I tried to print socket.getEnabledCipherSuites(); but printed strange text not a type of cipher suite at all.

EDIT:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

try{

    while ((there are IPs)   

    {
        try{
            //call for Connect function which has try/catch on it the same way

            }catch (Exception e){
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }//catch
    }//end while loop


   catch (Exception e){
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
 }//catch

 }//end void main </i>
```

Comment: can you provide the example code that uses the output of getEnabledCipherSuites and what you got as output ?

Comment: @sylvainulg The code is: String [] enabledCipher;
   enabledCipher=socket.getEnabledCipherSuites();
   System.out.println(enabledCipher);

Comment: The output: [Ljava.lang.String;@1adaaab0

Comment: your output seems to look like an array reference. You'll have to iterate over its members and print them separately.

Comment: A formatted sample of the output and the other instruction that prints out information, maybe ?

Comment: @Mem No need to loop, you can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enabledCipher));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your point #1 seems to be something exception handling should take care of: enclose each iteration on all_ips within its own try/catch block.

You could greatly benefit from some multithreading and time-out here, as some firewall will just drop your SYN packet silently and let your scanner tool wait indefinitely.

BUT before you do that, take care: you're going to look *very much* like a malicious tool scanning a network for some vulnerabilities. You may get into administrative trouble if you're too aggressive or target someone you don't know. A pool of thread or some similar technique to ensure you're not exceeding fair amount of connection establishment/second is a bare minimum.

Comment: thanks. I created try/catch in the single iteration level and the program continued. But another problem occurred: The program supposed to print out : SSL connection with site1., SSL connection with site2, ..etc. After I fixed the try/catch, the output is: ssl connection with site1 (which is with the disabled port), ssl connection with site 2 successful, then it prints the error: Error time out, it seems like there is a delay ?? or creating the next connection occur before the printout of the error message of the failed connection 1. How to solve such issue ??

Comment: that could arise if you have multiple thread and don't synchronize the output, or if you mix System.err and System.out. Try to have only one println(...) per information.

Comment: I'm not using threading. Here is the structure of the error handling. I guess I'm doing something wrong but don't know where exactly. Plz, check the edited post. thanx.